# RS-485 4-wire to 2-wire converter

Tags: communication, switching, rs485

I'm looking for a way to be able to electrically switch between 4-wire and 2-wire RS-485. Up until now I have used jumper connections to establish both communication ways with one circuit. But I would like to be able to switch electronically (from a MCU). An option would for example be a relay, but I don't have the power capabilities for this. Does any of you know of any known circuits that deal with this issue. A figure to describe this issue:

[image]

Comment: What will implement data flow-control?

Comment: The THVD1424 has this built in.

Comment: Thanks the THVD1424 was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

if you use a "2 wire" RS485 drivers you just need to gate the enable signal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQLlqY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>